# How can I use greater than on Gridview text?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a Gridview like this:

[image]

I need to change backcolor when `Zero` line greater than %10.

I tried like this (for just 15%):

```
if (e.Row.Cells[0].Text == "Zero")
{
   for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
   {
      if (e.Row.Cells[i].Text == "15%")
      {
         e.Row.Cells[i].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCoral;
      }
   }
}
```

I can't convert `Row.Cells[i].Text` to `Int` because of `%`. How can I use greater than 10 for backcolor?

Comment: Just remove `%` and then parse it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just replace

```
if (e.Row.Cells[i].Text == "15%")
```

with

```
if (int.Parse(e.Row.Cells[i].Text.Trim('%'))>10)
```

Comment: Getting error: `System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format`

Comment: I think because of `Zero`. I change `int i = 0` to `int i = 1` and its work. Thank you.